# TypeError: _this.props.editAp is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to call a function editAp in func.js page from Edit1.js page and I am unable to resolve this error. Code for func.js is :

```
import firebase from "firebase";
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp({});
}
export default function editAp(email, password, keyis) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.database().ref("/users1").child(keyis).update({ email, password });
  };
}
```

code for edit1.js is

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  StatusBar,
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  Alert,
  ScrollView,
} from "react-native";
import { editAp } from "../pages/func";
import firebase from "firebase";
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp({});
}
class Edit1 extends Component {
  state = {
    email: this.props.navigation.state.params.email,
    password: this.props.navigation.state.params.password,
    keyis: this.props.navigation.state.params.keyis,
  };
  submit1 = () => {
    console.log(this.props.navigation.state.params.keyis);
    console.log(this.state.email, this.state.password, this.state.keyis);
    this.props.editAp(this.state.email, this.state.password, this.state.keyis);
    this.setState({
      email: "",
      password: "",
      keyis: "",
    });
    Alert.alert("Action!", "user updated");
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Edit Here</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={{
            marginTop: 20,
            height: 40,
            borderColor: "gray",
            borderWidth: 1,
          }}
          onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({ email })}
          value={this.state.email}
        />
        <TextInput
          style={{
            marginTop: 20,
            height: 40,
            borderColor: "gray",
            borderWidth: 1,
          }}
          onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })}
          value={this.state.password}
        />
        <TextInput
          style={{
            marginTop: 20,
            height: 40,
            borderColor: "gray",
            borderWidth: 1,
          }}
          onChangeText={(keyis) => this.setState({ keyis })}
          value={this.state.keyis}
        />
        <Button title="Submit" onPress={this.submit1} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    padding: 30,
  },
});
export default Edit1;
```

Error which I am getting is TypeError: _this.props.editAp is not a function. (In '_this.props.editAp(_this.state.email, _this.state.password, _this.state.keyis)', '_this.props.editAp' is undefined)
I am trying to call the function in this page but unable to resolve it.

This is the page from where I am getting key, email, password to the Edit1.js page.

```
    import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {  Platform, StyleSheet, StatusBar, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, FlatList, TouchableHighlight, ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
if (!firebase.apps.length) {    firebase.initializeApp({}); }
class EditApollo extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={      users1:[]    }      }
  componentDidMount= () =>{
    firebase.database().ref('users1').once('value').then(snapshot => {
       var items = [];
       snapshot.forEach((child) => {
         items.push({
            keyis: firebase.database().ref().push().getKey(),
            email: child.val().email,
            password: child.val().password,
         });
      });
      this.setState({ users1: items});
      console.log('you',this.state.users1)
  });  }
   render() {
  return(
   <View style={styles.container}>
   <ScrollView>
   <FlatList style={{width:'100%'}}
data={this.state.users1}
keyExtractor={(elem)=>elem.key}
showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
renderItem={elem => (<View style={{elevation:8, width: 350, marginBottom:13, borderRadius:15, backgroundColor:'#575FCF', padding:15 }}>
  <Text style={{fontSize:18, fontWeight:'bold', color:'#fff'}}>{elem.item.email}</Text>
  <Text style={{fontSize:18, fontWeight:'bold', lineHeight:20, color:'#fff'}}>{elem.item.password}  </Text>
    <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'flex-end', marginTop:15 }}>
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Edit1',{...elem.item})}>
          <View style={{marginRight:15}}>
            <Icon size={25} color="white" name="edit" />
      </View>      </TouchableHighlight>        
      <TouchableHighligh>
          <View>                <Icon size={25} color="white" name="close" />          </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>            </View>
  </View>)}
/>
</ScrollView>
</View>
)}}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
 padding:10,
justifyContent:'center',
alignItems: 'center',
backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  row: {
    padding: 15,
    marginBottom: 5,
    backgroundColor: 'skyblue',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: 200,
 },
 item:{
backgroundColor: 'skyblue',
justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex : 1,
    margin: 1,
    height:50
 },
})
export default EditApollo;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not just 1 rather couple of issues in your code.

1) You have exported your function as default but you are importing it in `{}`

2) It's a util function which is not bind to `props` but you are doing `this.props.editAp`

3) Incorrect uses of Dispatch, in-fact it's not used at all. You are trying to use a util as an action.

Please try the below code and let me know if you see any issue

**func.js**

```js
import firebase from 'firebase';

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp({});
}

export function editAp(email, password, keyis) {
 firebase.database().ref('/users1').child(keyis).update({ email, password })
}
```

**edit1.js**

```js
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TextInput, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';

import { editAp } from '../pages/func';

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp({});
}

export default class EditScreen extends PureComponent {

  state = {
    email: this.props.navigation.state.params.email,
    password: this.props.navigation.state.params.password,
    keyis: this.props.navigation.state.params.keyis,
  };

  _submit = () => {
    const { email, password, keyis } = this.state;

    editAp(email, password, keyis);

    this.setState({
      email: '',
      password: '',
      keyis: '',
    });

    Alert.alert('Action!', 'user updated');
  };

  render() {
    const { email, password, keyis } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Edit Here</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={{ marginTop: 20, height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
          onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
          value={email}
        />
        <TextInput
          style={{ marginTop: 20, height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
          onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
          value={password}
        />
        <TextInput
          style={{ marginTop: 20, height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
          onChangeText={keyis => this.setState({ keyis })}
          value={keyis}
        />
        <Button title="Submit" onPress={this._submit} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    padding: 30,
  },
});
```

Comment: This solution worked but instead new entryis inserted and is not updated. Any solution for this can you help me out.

Comment: I will be happy to help out but I didn't get your question. If you are talking about data being not updated in firebase then I can try but 100% sure because of less knowledge on firebase.

Comment: New entry is inserted and updation is not taking place may be it is not getting the key from the database which we are sending via the function. and hence new entry is inserted.

Comment: Do console and check if correct `keyis` are getting passed or not. If not then check the `this.props.navigation.state.params.keyis`  to see if we have correct data in it or not. If at all we are getting data and it's being passed correctly then there might be some logic issue in how we are trying to update the DB.

Comment: Once value is inserted and i remove the code to blankout the fields so i can be on same page, then if i try to update the new inserted record then its happening. But after i press back button and try to update it, it isnt happening, I am posting my previous page that is from where data is coming onto this page. Hope that might help you to solve my error. Posted the code

Comment: I wish we had a chat option here. How much I am understanding this, it looks like issue in the state `keyis`. I guess we use this value to find the record in DB and if found then update else insert new record. I hope you are not doing any typo mistake.. :D  I would suggest simply console whole `this.state` in both of your cases and see whats the difference

Comment: I have consoled all the values and its perfectly doing well. If you want i can upload my files on drive and you can have a look in it if possible. All the values even in the next page remains the same nothing is changing. You can check the above code if you find any mistake let me know if possible

Comment: I guess something is going wrong with firebase update approach and I am not the right guy to help you on that I guess. I would suggest to start a new stack overflow discussion with firebase tag and all details on your issue. Sorry, I wasn't much help on this one.

Comment: Thanks for helping out, but i suppose this error is about passed value to edit1.js so I thought you could check it out.

Comment: @ChintanBhuta Well if you are sure then I think I got the issue. I have updated the code, please try the new one

Comment: Yes I tried with the changed code, same issue and when I tried with email and password as you told, I am unable to make changes in inputfield I guess due to if condition as you told to do it and hence I was not able to check with email and password as you told. And with key still same issue.

Comment: Sorry dude, if that doesn't help then I won't be able to help out more without whole code knowledge

Comment: shall I share the link of drive where I have put all the required folders

Comment: Sure but I might be looking at it after sometime

Answer (score 0):

Typo or wrong import, You are returning default as function. So return of import will be function.

**Use:**

```
import editAp  from "../pages/func";
```

**Else export as :**

```
function editAp(email, password, keyis) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.database().ref("/users1").child(keyis).update({ email, password });
  };
}
export { editAp }
```

Comment: This didnt work but previous solution worked. Just new entry is inserted instead of update.